# passing a list in python to generate url

Tags: python, github

I have to import my config.py file in my code and then basically pass the REPOS_TO_CHECK values to a function which should be in the form of a list such that when I pass the list to my build_url function which generates a url when the REPOS_TO_CHECK variable is passed to it from the config.py file

I have to generate the url like GET /repos/:owner/:repo
GITHUB_URL = 'https://testurl.com'

how do I pass the REPOS_TO_CHECK parameter from the config.py file as a list so that when I pass

```
def build_url(['owner','repo']):
```

the url generated will be `https://testurl.com/:owner/:repo`

```
:owner, :repo are in the REPOS_TO_CHECK in the config.py file.
```

I can access the config.py file by importing config.py in my code and then accessing the values by using the config. `for example: config.GITHUB_URL ,gives me 'https://testurl.com'`
This is my config file:

```
GITHUB_URL = 'https://testurl.com'
GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access token'
REPOS_TO_CHECK = [
    ('owner1', 'repo1'),
    ('owner2', 'repo2'),]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import your config.py as any other file given it's in the same folder: (otherwise navigate to it)

```
import config
```

Then you can call the variable like config.REPOS_TO_CHECK

To generate the url you can simply use the variables given in the function call:

If you're using python 3.6 use f strings:

```
def generate_url(list_here):
    return f'http://test.com/{list_here[0]}/{list_here[1]}'
```

Else use .format()

```
def generate_url(list_here):
    return 'http://test.com/{0}/{1}'.format(list_here[0], list_here[1])
```

Comment: I want to basically pass it as a list then generate the url